# Maximum number of participants on an Agora video call Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine, video, chat, agora.io

What is the maximum amount of participants you can have on an agora.io video call using the Agora Video SDK for Unity?

Comment: This is basically the very first search result for [`angora.io maximum participants`](https://www.google.com/search?q=agora.io+maximum+participants) -> [Frequently asked questions](https://www.agora.io/en/blog/some-frequently-asked-questions-by-our-developers/) -> `Audio Call: up to 10,000 people speaking at the same time. Video Call: up to 7 people at the same time (Video support for up to 25 people is under development).`

Comment: I guess there is such a thing as a stupid question. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It supports up to 10.000 people for audio call and up to 7 people for a video call although support for 25 people is currently under development.
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.agora.io/en/faq/capacity).

Answer (score 0):

### According to [Agora FAQ](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/faq/capacity):

> The Agora RTC SDK provides real-time audio and video services for many users. The number of concurrent channels is unlimited, and each channel supports up to 1 million concurrent online users.